# Can't delete face

Tags: modeling, faces

This face won't delete and it doesn't have any vertices. It is like an undetectable thin plane. Any help would mean so much, im just new to blender.[image]
Here is the blender file: [image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting objects in the outliner panel?

Comment: To my stupidity there are 50 of them and they are all un-named

Comment: I saw you have made surplus copies of meshes. See Text.000 and Text.004.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have 4 different objects that compose your brick. I guess you have 2 problems: the problem that you describe, and the problem that a lot of your faces are overlaying as there are part of 2 different objects. So, in my opinion, to fix this, you could join everything in one object with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, then remove doubles with a <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*, then delete the faces you want to delete. Note that you will have to fill the hole that you leave.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Only, when I delete these faces the rendered image still stays the same, and it also leaves an indent on the bottom of my lego piece.

Comment: ok I've edited my answer, perhaps it will be clearer

Answer (score 0):

It actually appears you're in edge selection mode, not face selection mode. Look closely at the bottom of the picture in the OP. Select face selection mode and try to select the face that way.

Comment: Yeh, in the picture I was in edge selection mode, but even when I switched to face selection mode I still couldn't select or delete it.